# JavaScript lib for google maps or live maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, virtual-earth

Can anyone recomend a good javascript lib for working with Google Maps or Live Maps(virtualearth )?

Is jQuery og Prototype something to consider?

I think I remember that asp.net ajax had some controls and hooks for working with virtual earth back in the day, but cant seem to find it any more.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both jQuery and Prototype. They both have their ups and downs, however I recently switched from Prototype to jQuery and have really been enjoying it.

Here is a link to the [Google jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jmaps/) plugin.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery and Prototype are "general" JS frameworks (for lack of a better word), mostly aimed at manipulating the DOM/handling events etc. You want one of the Map APIs:

- [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/)
- [Yahoo Maps JS API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/)
- [Virtual Earth SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905677.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Google's own [Javascript Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-js.html) can be used to interact with various google services, including maps.

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn this was already available. Looks like it isn't still. The Dojo toolkit might be the first to implement it, though. Look for developments [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojox-dojox/dojox-development-discussion/call-geo-features).